# Specifying the same gem twice for development/test and production but different paths

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, github

Sometimes you make a gem that is specific to a project. This helps abstract and pull some of the "responsibility" out of the main Rails app and into a more modular place.

The gem would be located here on you application:

```
gem 'example_gem', path: './example_gem'
```

You bundle and everything is OK. Now, you `git init` the gem and store it in its own repo on github. You try doing this to keep it developer friendly:

```
group :development, :test do
  gem 'example_gem', path: './example_gem'
end

group :production do
  gem 'example_gem', github: 'company/example_gem'
end
```

You pat yourself on the back for increasing your workflow, but after running `bundle` you get:

```
Your Gemfile lists the gem example_gem (>= 0) more than once.
You should probably keep only one of them.
While it's not a problem now, it could cause errors if you change the version of just one of them later.
You cannot specify the same gem twice coming from different sources.
You specified that example_gem (>= 0) should come from source at ./example_gem and git://github.com/company/example_gem.git
```

The workflow here is to be able to edit the gem in development and when you're done, commit those changes and push them to Github. BUT, when on development, you don't want to have to do a git commit, git push, and a bundle update on your main app just to see a small change.

Does anyone know of a better way to solve this issue?

Comment: why do you can't access to github on develop and test environments?

Comment: example_gem is it an external dependency of current project. Your changes of   current project should be independent of example_gem

Comment: I don't think you understand what's happening here @kikicarbonell. If you have to make changes to a gem and you want to see the changes reflected in the app, you must commit, push, and then bundle update to see those changes. To get past this, you have the `path`. The issue arises when you have to commit the code. If you have `example_gem` in your `.gitignore` your app will crash in production. This begins to become a hassle to switch the path and the github back and forth...

Comment: Also @kikicarbonell can you update the grammar? I'm not sure what questions you're asking.

Comment: In this context, the example_gem is just abstracted code from your project. Therefore, example_gem is not actually an "external dependency", but a dependency none the less.

Comment: You can try to use the idea of git submodules to solve this situation (Ref: http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules). Also @BenMorganIO sorry for my previous grammar.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, there is a better way: First, have the gem as a git gem in all environments

```
gem :example_gem, :git => 'git@github.com:foo/example_gem', :branch => :master #you need to set a branch
```

Then in your app's folder run

```
bundle config --local local.example_gem /path/to/gem
```

This will edit .bundle/config to set this option (make sure this file isn't checked into source control!) and tells bundler to get the gem from that path.

At the point when you are going to push your commits you have to be a little bit careful: if your app depends on not yet committed changes to the gem then clearly things will break. In addition as you commit to the repository for the example gem the rails app's Gemfile.lock will get updated. If you push a Gemfile.lock that references a commit that only exists in your copy of the example_gem repo then other users will be stuck.

Comment: Important to note that this only works for gems that are using `:git` in the `Gemfile` and where the branch is the same in the `Gemfile` and the local path. See https://github.com/bundler/bundler/issues/3645

Answer (score 0):

this works for me.

```
foo = "https://github.com/me/my-development-version-gem.git"
group :production do
    foo = "https://github.com/me/my-production-version-gem.git"
end
gem "foo", :git => foo
```

in my case i need different branchs for envs to engine

Comment: Caution: This does not work unless you rerun bundler on the production system. `Gemfile.lock` will not be correctly created for multiple environment following this answer.